# Loading a purchased jquery plugin in a wordpress theme

Tags: plugins, jquery

I purchased a 360 Panorama jQuery plugin that I would like to integrate into my wordpress site. All the tutorials I've read said to include the function add_my_script() and
wp_enqueue_script tags to import the plugin to the site, but my question is how do I activate the plugin on a specific page. I am a beginner in Wordpress so I apologize is this is a stupid question, but I could not find the answer anywhere online.

Comment: There could be many solutions for this, but depends on how you need to display the Panorama, and on what information needs to be fed to it. This [search results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bwp_enqueue_scripts+%2Badd_shortcode) may give you a starting point.

Comment: If for example the page ID of the page you want it loaded on is 5, then you can try it like this: `if ( is_single( '5' ) ) { wp_enqueue_script(.......); }` I hope that helps!